# Ef Core Global Query Filter Enable Disable Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, global-query-filter

I'm trying to implement an ef core global query filter with enable disable conditions. According to my scenario, I have a flag called '**FilterStatus**' and its value changes to every user. So any user logged in to the system **FilterStatus** value is changed. I want to implement a global query filter to filter data according to the **FilterStatus** flag.

I've come up with the following but does not work if-else statement of global query filter:

```csharp
public partial class TableDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    protected Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    protected UserClaimFilter UserClaimFilter { get; set; } = new UserClaimFilter();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var tenant = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.GetTenant();
        if (tenant != null)
        {
            TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenant.Id);
            var userClaims = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session
                .GetObject<UserClaimFilter>(DefaultConstants.SessionUserClaimStore);

            if (userClaims != null)
            {
                UserClaimFilter = userClaims;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>(entity =>
        {
            if (UserClaimFilter.FilterStatus && UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Any())
            {
                entity.HasQueryFilter(a => a.TenantId == TenantId 
                    && UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Contains(a.RegionCode));
            }
            else
            {
                entity.HasQueryFilter(a => a.TenantId == TenantId);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code always run the else part even if the **UserClaimFilter.FilterStatus** is true. I think because of the first time running the OnModelCreating default value of **UserClaimFilter.FilterStatus** is false.

Any solution to enable-disable global query filter according to the configuration value?

Comment: `UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Any()` also must be true to satisfy the condition. Something really weird about this code is the way you initialize the `UserClaimFilter` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the dynamic parts of the global query filter conditions must (1) originate from `DbContext` members (as with your code) and (2) be part of the expression rather than evaluated once when building the expression. EF Core has mechanism for eliminating the constant true or false parts of conditional expressions when translating the query, so all you need is to include them in the expression. e.g.

```cs
entity.HasQueryFilter(a => a.TenantId == TenantId &&
    (!UserClaimFilter.FilterStatus ||
     !UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Any() || 
     UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Contains(a.RegionCode))
);
```

When applying the filter to a query, if `!UserClaimFilter.FilterStatus` or `!UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Any()` is true *at that time*, then the whole expression `(a || b || c)` will be considered *constant* true and eliminated from the generated query (because `(x && true) == x`).

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, currently EF Core does not fully eliminate the whole expression. `a || b` are replaced with `bool` parameter having either `true` or `false` value. But at least `c` (which is the actual filter, `UserClaimFilter.RegionClaims.Contains(a.RegionCode)` in your case) is eliminated when the `bool` parameter value is `true`.

Comment: Year ago i saw that EF Core do not optimize query filters. It is improved?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You mean in query filters? In "normal" queries this always worked, didn't know query filters work differently in that regard. Probably have to check. Even though (optimized or not), this is the only way to get dynamic filter.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Ok, you are right (partially). The `WHERE` incudes some fake `AND @__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit)` and passing bool parameter with value `true`. But at least there is no `EXISTS` part. In the other case,  condition is `AND (@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit) OR EXISTS(...))`, still binding bool parameter with value `false`  this time. I guess the sql query optimizer should be able to eliminate these fake (basically always true) conditions similar to `WHERE 1=1` etc.

Comment: However this is in EFC 6.0, and I  just saw EFC 3.1 tag in the question. So it would do whatever you've saw I guess. Still the "dynamic" filter will work (produce correct results), even though in non optimal way (in case sql query optimizer is not smart enough to do such SQL query optimizations).

Comment: EFC do not translate local collections to query. That's why there is no EXISTS part. Actually they check that expression can be compliable and introduce parameter which is evaluated from expression.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This is not using local collection. There is local collection involved, but just for `Contains` part, which as you know is translated to `IN(values)`. Forget about `EXISTS`, I was testing child collection criteria. With OP sample, the conditions are either `param = CAST(1 as bit)` or `(param = CAST(1 as bit) OR [table].[col] IN (val1, val2, ...))`. So the `IN` is eliminated when the param value is `true`. Hence the only defect is the parameter and condition using it. But this is in 6.0